# Browser flashes for split second when submitting form to an iframe

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser, iframe, file-upload

I'm trying to do a fake Ajax file upload with an iframe. When I submit the form, the browser window would flash white for a split second. Here's my code:

```
$('#element input[type="file"]').change(function() {
    $('#somediv').append('<iframe src="/" name="uploadFrame"></iframe>');
    $('#somediv form').attr('target', 'uploadFrame').submit();
  });
```

Comment: Does your page have a valid doctype? is the flash happening in all browsers?

Comment: Yes. <!DOCTYPE html>. Due to the fact I'm developing the app with a cookie based authentication and I haven't certain views, I can't test the it in another browser yet. I don't get the flash when I use other examples online.

Comment: What browser is it happening in? I've been using code VERY similar for about a year now without issues.

Comment: Safari 5.1.1 on the Mac.

Comment: The site is up. http://mocku.ps/ try uploading and you can see the flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding:

```
 width="0" height="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
```

To the iframe solved the problem.